# sed replace two double quotes and keep text

Tags: bash, sed, replace

Text to be processed :

```
""text""
"text"
""
```

output desired :

```
"text"
"text"
""
```

Tried with :

```
 echo -e '""text""\n"text"\n""' | sed -e 's/"".*""/".*"/g'
```

But obviously no luck.

Cheers,

Comment: could be there a line `""""" ""` ? If so - how should it be processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a backreference (something that refers to a previously matched part) in your sed command :

```
echo -e '""text""\n"text"\n""' | sed -E -e 's/""(.*)""/"\1"/g'
```

Here are the modifications I did :

- I grouped what was inside the double-quote in the matching pattern with `(...)`
- I referenced that matching group in the replacement pattern with `\1`
- I told sed to use `-E`xtended regex so I wouldn't have to escape the grouping parenthesis

Answer (score 3):

Based on your sample input, you could just use this:

```
sed '/^""$/! s/""/"/g' file
```

On lines which don't only contain two double quotes, globally replace all pairs of double quotes with one double quote.

Comment: @Sundeep thanks, I wanted to use `!` but I was putting it before the pattern (like in awk)  and it wasn't working

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's/"\("[^"]*"\)"/\1/' file
"text"
"text"
""
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: No it wouldn't. It's utterly trivial and self explanatory. Don't comment on answers the tool flags as **possibly** low quality if you don't understand the domain. The tool flags it so a human with knowledge can weigh in on it, having someone rubber-stamping the flag is a complete waste of time. If all answers without explanation really were a problem then the tool itself could just make the comment but that's just not the case.

Comment: I agree that the answer can be elaborated. This answer works for me. Added /g to make the search global.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following awk command and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -v s1="\"" '!/^\"\"$/{gsub(/\"\"/,s1)} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: Lots of unnecessary escaping here (could be `awk -v s1='"' '!/^""$/{gsub(/""/,s1)} 1'` and I don't know why you would prefer awk (with gsub and no implicit print) over sed.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
cat file | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/^/"/g' | sed 's/$/"/g'
```

**Details**

`sed 's/"//g'` remove all double quote

`sed 's/^/"/g'` put a double quote at the beginning of each line

`sed 's/$/"/g'` put a double quote at the end of each line

**Note**

This approach will work only if there is one word per line, like in your example.

Comment: no need to use `cat`, you can specify multiple substitutions in single `sed` command and no need `g` for single replacements... `sed 's/"//g; s/^/"/; s/$/"/' file`

Answer (score -1):

Answer by Aaron is also fine but back-referencing is costlier in general. Why not use a simpler command:

```
echo -e '""text""\n"text"\n""' | sed 's/""*/"/g'
```

Regex to replace more than one double quote to single one.

Comment: Yup missed it !

Answer (score -1):

```
echo -e '""text""\n"text"\n""' |awk '/""text""/{gsub(/""/,"\42")}1'

"text"
"text"
""
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your solution is not generic.. agree though that OP should have given better sample... you might as well do a simple `sed 's/""text""/"text"/'`

Comment: I missed OP didn't ask for an awk option I will try to be more alert in the future.

Comment: You have provided a solution that is very limited compared to the others that were posted previously and you have not provided any useful explanation.